FastReport fails to execute in Docker
Im trying to run a container with FastReport. Image builds correctly, but container fails to execute.
Dockerfile:
FROM debian:buster-slim

ENV MONO_VERSION 6.8.0.105

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg dirmngr ca-certificates \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
  && gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
  && gpg --batch --export --armor 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mono.gpg.asc \
  && gpgconf --kill all \
  && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" \
  && apt-key list | grep Xamarin \
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gnupg dirmngr

RUN echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-buster/snapshots/$MONO_VERSION main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mono-runtime
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*

RUN mono --version
WORKDIR /app
COPY FREPRunner.exe FREPRunner.exe.config ./FREPRunner/ ./
CMD ["mono", "FREPRunner.exe"]

And exception that i got:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'FastReport.Report:measureBitmap' (30) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
  at FastReportRunner.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00013] in <03ee2ed2799f40b1bca347b97dbdeed9>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'FastReport.Report:measureBitmap' (30) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
  at FastReportRunner.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00013] in <03ee2ed2799f40b1bca347b97dbdeed9>:0

I've tried to install .NET sdk and run dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common in project directory, but it didn't help.
I've found this on microsoft website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only
